# Can't create/write to file MYSQL to directory different of /var/tmp

Tags: php, mysql, permissions

Server version: 5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (Ubuntu)

I am trying to save output to file: `/var/www/dir/file.csv`

It gives me an error: Can't create/write to file '/var/www/dir/file.csv' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)

It is PHP script, executing through browser.

Permissions: `/dir/ (ls -al)`

`drwxrwxrwx  2 mysql root  4096 Apr 29 10:40 dir`

Answer (score 1):

I think you have set this option in your MySQL-Server:

[secure_file_priv](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv)

Comment: Yes, it was : secure-file-priv = ""
But if i'll remove it, I get error:
`The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement`

Answer (score 0):

I have found that default dir to upload files is: `/var/lib/mysql-files/`

`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";`

And rewrite script to write in that directory.

Comment: Yes, the best solution is to use this path. To disable this rule is not recommended

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you need to adjust secure_file_priv variable, but you will also need to adjust your AppArmor configuration on Ubuntu (SELinux if it was Fedora/CentOS/RedHat) to allow you to write to the directory outside of the ones already allowed.